# First characters of the command repeated in the display when completing

Tags: zsh, line-editor, oh-my-zsh

The first two chars were repeated while I use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to do completion. In the screenshot below, `cd` is repeated.

[image]

I have tried rxvt-unicdoe, xterm, terminator.  All these terminal emulators have this issue.

Zsh version 5.0.2, config file [on-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh.git)

Comment: Are the characters repeated in the command that zsh executes, or are they merely displayed? Does the number of characters change if the command is longer than two characters? Does the number change when the current directory changes?

Comment: @Gilles The repeated char not exists in the command. I can execute command.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If the characters on your command line are sometimes displayed at an offset, this is often because zsh has computed the wrong width for the prompt. The symptoms are that the display looks fine as long as you're adding characters or moving character by character but becomes garbled (with some characters appearing further right than they should) when you use other commands that move the cursor (<kbd>Home</kbd>, completion, etc.) or when the command overlaps a second line.

Zsh needs to know the width of the [prompt](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Visual-effects) in order to know where the characters of the command are placed. It assumes that each character occupies one position unless told otherwise.

One possibility is that your prompt contains **escape sequences** which are not properly delimited. Escape sequences that change the color or other formatting aspects of the text, or that change the window title or other effects, have zero width. They **need to be included within a percent-braces construct `%{…%}`**. More generally, an escape sequence like `%42{…%}` tells zsh to assume that what is inside the braces is 42 characters wide.

So check your prompt settings (`PS1`, `PROMPT`, or the variables that they reference) and make sure that all escape sequences (such as `\e[…m` to change text attributes — note that it may be present via some variable like `$fg[red]`) are inside `%{…%}`. Since you're using oh-my-zsh, check both your own settings and the definitions that you're using from oh-my-zsh.

The same issue arises in bash. There zero-width sequences in a [prompt](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Printing-a-Prompt) need to be enclosed in `\[…\]`.

Another possibility is that your prompt contains non-ASCII characters and that zsh (or any other application) and your terminal have a different idea of how wide they are. This can happen if there is a **mismatch between the encoding** of your terminal and the encoding that is declared in the shell, and the two encodings result in different widths for certain byte sequences. Typically you might run into this issue when using a non-Unicode terminal but declaring a Unicode locale or vice versa.

Applications rely on environment variables to know the locale; the relevant setting is `LC_CTYPE`, which is determined from the environment variables `LANGUAGE`, `LC_ALL`, `LC_CTYPE` and `LANG` (the first of these that is set applies). The command `locale | grep LC_CTYPE` tells you your current setting. Usually the best way to avoid locale issues is to let the terminal emulator set `LC_CTYPE`, since it knows what encoding it expects; but if that's not working for you, make sure to set `LC_CTYPE`.

The same symptoms can occur when the previous command displayed some output that didn't end in a newline, so that the prompt is displayed in the middle of the line but the shell doesn't realize that. In this case that would only happen after running such a command, not persistently.

If a line isn't displayed properly, the command `redisplay` or `clear-screen` (bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> by default) will fix it.

Comment: I guess I am probably missing related font, I notice the first char is strange. It is expected to be `->` I think

Comment: @jilen Ah, this could be another issue that I forgot to mention: maybe your prompt contains non-ASCII characters in a different encoding from your terminal, with one or both of the encodings being multibyte. If you want help with that, post the output of `locale` and of `echo $PS1 | od -t x1` (and the same thing with any other variable used by `$PS1`).

Comment: I forgot to set the locale(I am using archlinux, locale are left not set by default) . After set locale , this problem are fixed. Thanks a lot, guy!!!!

Comment: I upvoted it because, well, it's pretty awesome. But escapes needn't absolutely be included in the brackets if you otherwise handle the cursor count on your own. calling a subshelled function has worked for me in the past - or redirections that still land on /dev/tty without involving stdout might work. Other methods that have worked - using `\e{7,8}` to save/restore cursor states.

Comment: It was the `LC_CTYPE` that fixed it for me. I had it set to `C`, when I unset it, everything worked. Thanks.

Comment: Does all of the above apply to shells other than `zsh` too?

Comment: @MattPotts The principle does. The syntax and command names are different in different shells.

Comment: The locale didn't fix it for me and nor did this "If a line isn't displayed properly, the command redisplay or clear-screen (bound to Ctrl+L by default) will fix it."

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem and found my solution here: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/5157#issuecomment-226031519. Simply put the following into your `~/.zshrc`.

`export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: Thanks for your hint! I, however, had to reset the whole `locale` i was using, but it worked for me. [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/227513) provides the necessary steps for Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you so much! Saved me alot of aggrevation

Comment: Didn't work here.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue in iTerm 2 on macOS. I ended up solving it by going to Preferences -> Profiles -> Text and ticking off "Use Unicode Version 9 Widths".

Comment: Wow, this actually worked. Thanks!

Comment: Same, although the reverse worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've got this issue using ubuntu lts docker image (`ubuntu:latest`). I fixed it with instruction provided on the corresponding page: https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu

```
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y locales && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_US.UTF-8
echo 'export LANG=en_US.utf8' >> ~/.zshrc
zsh
```