# zsh+tmux in Mac OS Ventura: line wrapping occurs at every typing

Tags: zsh, tmux, macos

When updated to Mac OS Ventura, I found trouble using `zsh` and `tmux`. Line wrapping happens when I hit the keyboard. Please check the screenshot below. In this case, I just typed `lspwa`. Any idea for this issue? Thanks a lot.

[image: wrapping occurs at every typing]

Comment: This kind of issues is often caused by [prompt settings that don't properly indicate zero-width parts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90772/first-characters-of-the-command-repeated-in-the-display-when-completing). If that's not it, we'll need more information to help you. In particular, you need to post your complete zsh settings.

Comment: Another possibility is that your terminal type is not declared properly. The terminal type is declared automatically through the `TERM` environment variable. If you're setting `TERM` manually, don't. It is almost never useful to set `TERM` manually, and it usually causes problems. Setting `TERMINFO` or `TERMCAP` manually could be a problem too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This issue didn't occur until I updated Mac OS from Monterey to Ventura (I didn't change any settings). I think you are right. Seems the auto-completion of oh-my-zsh is triggered every time when I hit a key. Unfortunately, all the solutions mentioned in those threads don't work for me :S

Comment: Thanks, Gilles! Finally, I solved it by adding "export TERM=screen-256color" in my .zshrc. It works perfectly when I call tmux on my MacBook pro (intel). However, on my Mac mini (M1), another issue came out. Hot keys doesn't work, e.g., "ctrl+B" gave me "^B". I haven't solved it, but I change to bash under tmux, which works well.

Comment: Finally, I solved this trouble. I added "bindkey -e" in .zshrc. Now everything works perfectly.